# What is the best method for video Upload in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, video, flv, video-player

What is the best method for video Upload and Playing it in PHP .  I don't want to upload to youtube. Should I convert to any format after upload ? And please suggest which player should I use to play it ? I am using PHP condeigntier framework.

Comment: What do you mean by best method? What is your OS? Do you have a budget? Have you tried anything at all? What research have you made so far? Please see the FAQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any upload script for this.

You should use ffmpeg for encoding video files to flv format.

Here is the article.

http://youtubeclone.wordpress.com/2007/05/26/how-to-convertencode-files-to-flv-using-ffmpeg-php/

Answer (score 1):

i use flowplayer for play video on browser. for upload swfupload utility is good for upload multiple video at a time. up to 30MB